# How do I analyze a sequence of events on a per user basis in a database?

Tags: data-visualization

I am looking for a way to analyze typical user behavior with a very large number of events. The events have names, user id's and other non-vital attributes. It would be very helpful for seeing use patterns if we could make a graph, similar to the following mock-up:
[image: Flow Graph]

There are obviously flaws with this graph, but I think the idea is clear. Essentially, given a particular event, what events are most likely to occur next and what are their percentages respectively. It seems like a very doable task, but using industry tools like Tableau, I have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Can you assume that people's next action only depends on where they are now?

Comment: Have a look at Disco: https://fluxicon.com/disco/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is Process Mining. Process mining takes a event log (a sequence of events grouped by some ID) and derives a process that could produce that event log.

You can use this for simply discovering a process and learning about it (and then improving it), or to compare the discovered process with a documented process to look for variations (people not following procedure, or events that are not covered by the specified process).

There is free open-source software for processing mining. PRoM (http://www.promtools.org/doku.php) is the main one. More user friendly is the commercial software Disco by Fluxicon (https://fluxicon.com/disco/).

Comment: This looks like a great tool. Checkin on price, but my only current complaint is that it does not support SQL connections.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of a network analysis software tool such as *Ucinet* exported to a visualization tool such as *Pajek* would probably work. Both are free to download...

https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/downloads

http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pajek/